# Fortify scan gives unreleased resources socket error on using HTTP Client

Tags: java, sockets, apache-httpclient-4.x, fortify, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using fortify to scan warnings and errors.
one of the errors is flagged high.

The implementation is  that of simple HTTP client

```
HttpPost postReq = new HttpPost(url);

try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()
        CloseableHttpResponse postResp = httpClient.execute(postReq);) { ... }
```

I assumed that try with resources will handle graceful exit for **CloseableHttpClient**  and **CloseableHttpResponse**

However it does not handle the same. I tried closing it separately in finally block - using `httpClient.close()` and using  `EntityUtils.consume(posResp.getEntity())`,  still the error flagged is Unreleased resources : Sockets.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? If yes how ?